# Ubuntu 12.04 crashes after selecting 'Try Without Installing' on Windows PC

Tags: 12.04, system-installation, virtualization

I've been following this tutorial

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/InstallingUbuntu104LTSOnWindowsVirtualPCOnWindows7.aspx

However, when it comes to selecting 'Try Without Installing', the virtual machine simply closes down.

Edit:
In fact it closes down no matter what I select from the menu, 'Install Ubuntu', 'Check CD for Defects' ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That tutorial is for a very old version of Ubuntu which is not supported any more.

Windows virtual PC is also optimised for creating Virtual Windows machines and lots of people have had problems with it when trying to install other operating systems. I suggest you use Virtualbox instead.  This is a more general Virtual machine and It will certainly work well with a Windows 7 host.

I would recommend you use either Ubuntu 13.04 as the guest or if you want to use 12.04 I would avoid the standard Ubuntu and use either Lubuntu or Xubuntu instead.  I had problems with Ubuntu being very slow due to the lack of a real separate graphics processor using 12.04 and 12.10 in a virtual machine with the default Unity desktop.  However these issues have been fixed with 13.04 and the lighter desktops used in Lubuntu and Xubuntu have never been an issue.

You can find the Virtualbox download for Windows [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads).  Once you have installed Ubuntu, Xubuntu or Lubuntu install Guest additions for best performance.